# "Change your phone number?" notification

Tags: notifications, google-play-services, google-pixel

Since I got my new Google Pixel, I've received a "Change your phone number?" notification upon each boot up. Nothing I've done has remedied the issue...

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Selected the notification, provided my credentials, updated my phone number (which has been the same for years), and applied the changes.
2. Rebooted lots of times.
3. Wiped the cache for Google Play and Google Play Services.
4. Removed my account's recovery phone number, then re-added my phone number.
5. Removed my Google account from the phone, then added it again.

Short of factory resetting the device, I'm not sure what else to try. This issue has been going on for 8 days now. It's rather frustrating.

Here's a screenshot of the issue:

[image: Here's a screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Install [this app] (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) to see which app is responsible for this. Maybe that will help in next steps

Comment: @beeshyams Downloaded the app and rebooted. The notification was created by Google Play Services.

Comment: IDK what's to be done since you don't want to reset. Was hoping it would be an errant app that can be uninstalled​

Comment: You can try uninstalling the updates of Google play store, deleting cache and data of it and updating again. Sometimes it fixes things. You have cleared cache but not data as per Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd follow up on this. After trying just about everything, I caved and factory reset my phone. The notification hasn't appeared since.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the ultimate 'answer' to your question, but I too received a similar notification from Google Play services just yesterday:[image]
As you can see, mine is slightly different in that it was asking for me to "add" my "new" number as opposed to change it. The thing is, my phone is not new (2 year old Nexus 5X, most recently fully reset more than 9 months ago), nor are any of my account/numbers, and I have not done anything recently in the way of adding phone numbers (cellular or Google Voice) or recently connecting Google accounts to the device.

At first blush the message I received just looks like Google attempting to get people to fill in the phone number field on all Google accounts, but that doesn't make sense in my case as the account referenced does have a phone number configured for security purposes. Even if the specific field they care about is empty I don't know why they would have worded the message as such, making it sound like they are somehow aware of a "new" number added to my phone, somewhere. It really was a strange notification to receive.

So with that said, I wonder if your similar notification on your Pixel is a symptom of a larger issue Google is having on their back-end systems. So far I have only received my bizarre notification once, it didn't coincide with a restart of the phone, and restarting the phone now doesn't seem to trigger it. So again, this may not be the ultimate answer to your specific symptom, but it seems like Google has gone notification happy with Google Play services soliciting phone number input.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: I was getting the same message on my phone so I went into my Google account with my PC and found that one of my recovery email addresses was invalid (I had closed one of the accounts).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem here is what I did
went to apps > google play services > force stop > storage > clean all data there>
now disable google play services and erase all data
now go again apps > play store > force stop > storage> clean all data there

Restart phone
now google play store will ask to update google play services > update > restart

done notification didn't appear when restarted my phone anymore

Comment: All those ">" on one line makes it look like you're going very, very deep into a menu or something. This answer needs something to separate actions. Perhaps more punctuation or line returns.